# Create custom reports with crystal reports and entity framework 4

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4, crystal-reports

I want to allow users of a asp.net mvc 2 application, creating dynamicly reports. In a SQLServer Database is a table with all tasks for a user. Every task depends on a project and a user. What I want to do is to create some reports like "show me all tasks for the project X" or "Show me all my tasks" but also something like "Show me all my tasks with the status X for project Y". This lists should be exportable as PDF or CSV. And it would be also nice if it is possible to show this lists in a asp.net mvc view.

I read a lot about crystal reports and it seems that what I want is possible with it. I found some tutorials which explain how to show all columns of a table in the report. But what I don't understand is how I can set some conditions "on the fly".

It would be very nice if something like the following pseudocode will do what I want:

```
// Load the tasks with Entity Framework by reference to some Condition
List<Task> tasks = GetTasks(userId); 

// Load the reportfile
var report = GetChristalReport("Name of the .rpt report file");

// Set the loaded entities to the report
report.setData(tasks);

// Export it to pdf or do what you want with the rendered report
var pdf = report.ExportToPdf();
```

I hope you can help me and say if this is possible with chrystal reports and how I can implement this.

Comment: does the output file need to be viewed in the ASP or just saved to disk? If it does need to be viewed in ASP would it need to be viewed as PDF, rpt etc. ?

Comment: It would be nice if it can be viewed in ASP but it is not a must have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you mention is not only possible but relatively easy to do in CR. Most of what you need to do is to create a ReportDocument object, call repDoc.Load("myReport.rpt"); and then repDoc.ExportToDisk(fileFormat, fileName); and you're done. If you want to view it in the asp as an rpt file you need to create a ReportViewer object which is a little difficult but ASP natively supports viewing pdf in browser. I hope that helps

Comment: Ok, I understand in wich way I should display the report. But I still not understand how I can set the data for the report. I dont want to show all data of a table. I want to create a condition depends on user input. Something like "with creation date betweed last Monday and today". What I try is to set a list of entity framework objects as datasource for the report

Comment: to restrict the data shown in the report you add parameters to the report in the report designer

Comment: Do you have a simple example or a tutorial which explains this?

Comment: if you type "add parameters" into the report designer help there is a good example there